# Format Conversion Failed when Pushing JSON File into Firehose

Tags: python, json, pandas, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a pandas dataframe `stocks_df` which is as follows:

```
| Date      | Price|Symbol|
|-----------|------|------|
| 2022-07-10|150.54| APPL |
```

I need to convert it to JSON and push it into firehose

```
{"Date":"2022-07-11","Price":65.09,"Symbol":"ACM"}
```

I am getting some error and a folder is created in my S3 bucket `format-conversion-failed/` with the following in the file:

```
{"attemptsMade":1,"arrivalTimestamp":1657602058357,"lastErrorCode":"DataFormatConversion.MalformedData","lastErrorMessage":"The input JSON contained a primitive at the top level. The top level must be an object or array.","attemptEndingTimestamp":1657602335593,"rawData":"IntcIkRhdGVcIjpcIjIwMjItMDctMTFcIixcIlByaWNlXCI6OC4yNixcIlN5bWJvbFwiOlwiQUNSXCJ9Ig==","sequenceNumber":"49631306863317095792192735938176634752612190707410534402","subSequenceNumber":null,"dataCatalogTable":{"catalogId":null,"databaseName":"XXXXXX","tableName":"XXXXXXXXX","region":"us-east-1","versionId":"LATEST","roleArn":"arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:role/service-role/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-PUT-S3-bndnet-us-east-1-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}}
```

this is the decoded value from RawData: `"{\"Date\":\"2022-07-11\",\"Price\":0.16,\"Symbol\":\"ACQRW\"}"`

This is my function:

```
def push_file_to_firehose(stocks_df):
    fh = boto3.client('firehose')
    stocks_json = stocks_df.to_json(orient='records').strip('[]')
    logger.info(stocks_json)
    try: 
        fh.put_record(DeliveryStreamName='PUT-S3-bndnetworks', \
        Record={'Data': json.dumps(stocks_json)} )
        logger.info("Successfully pushed the file into Firehose")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error while pushing the file into Firehose")
        logging.error(e)
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of `Data` must be `base64` encoded (`bytes`), not a JSON string (`str`).

Example:

```py
import base64
import json

fh.put_record(
    DeliveryStreamName='PUT-S3-bndnetworks',
    Record={
        'Data': base64.b64encode(
            json.dumps(stocks_json).encode('utf-8')
        ).decode('utf-8')
    }
)
```

Reference: [`put_record()` (boto)](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/firehose.html#Firehose.Client.put_record) (admittedly, the documentation is kind of confusing)